# telling Icicles to ignore matches when creating a file

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, icicles

I use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) for auto-completion when for example finding a file in emacs. However sometimes I need to create a file with a particular name `filename.tex` in a directory and the autcomplete automatically finds a file with a similar name `filanem_another.tex` in another directory (I'm guessing from history).

This is annoying as it prevents making new files using `C-x C-f` and instead finds a similar file.

How can I ignore Icicles's suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to provide a step-by-step recipe of what you do.  So far, I don't recognize the behavior you describe.  What do you mean by "autocompletion" and "Icicles's suggestions", for example?

Also mention whether you have any 
**Icicles** customizations.  Best is a recipe that starts from `emacs -Q` (no init file), saying exactly what to do to reproduce the problem.  And please mention your `emacs-version`.

By default, in *Icicle* mode `C-x C-f` is bound to `icicle-file`.  You should be able to enter any file name you like at the prompt; you need not choose any of the completion candidates, and you need not even complete (`TAB` or `S-TAB`).  (And completion does not complete against the history.)  IOW, in these respects `C-x C-f` should behave the same as in vanilla Emacs.

[To those tempted to complain that this is a comment and not a real answer: I intend to answer the question here, when I get some more info about it.]